# Rails 3.1 - specifying attributes not part of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Newbie question - I have an assets model which is polymorphic (assetable_type, assetable_id). One type is is a Product. I'd like to add a caption to products assets only; there is not a caption field in the database so want to create from the other product in question. I'm currently not interested in the other side of the polymorphic as outlined here http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/3/polymorphic-through (not even sure if that technique would be current.)

I came up with this but it seems a little inelegant (ok, a lot).

```
def caption
  if self.assetable_type=='Product'
    p=Product.find(self.assetable_id)
    t=p.header
    t+=" - " + p.detail unless p.detail.nil?
  end
  return t
end
```

Would it be better to use `read_attribute` for this? Would this even be considered an attribute? Any ideas on improving this fragment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
def caption
  @caption ||= if self.assetable_type == 'Product'
    product = Product.find(self.assetable_id)
    caption = product.header
    caption + = " - " + product.detail unless product.detail.nil?
  end
end
```